# Simple AngularJS app with service does not work

Tags: angularjs

I've got a very simple angular app that I can not figure out what is wrong with.  The code is on plunkr here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/QQkP2HB6VGv50KDdBPag?p=preview and generates the error:  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: testService

The code is below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>simple problem I can not figure out</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function() {
            'use strict';

            var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

            myAppModule.service('testService', function (testService) {
            });

            myAppModule.config(['testService',
                function (testService) {
            }]);

        })();

        </script>

    </head>
    <body >
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div>
           myApp Here
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are injecting the service into itself?

Comment: `myAppModule.service('testService', function (testService) {` ? You are trying to inject `testService` in testservice? And you cannot inject `testService` inside config because service would not have been instantiated yet.

Comment: @Mathew-green  I'm trying to create the service and then use it in the module.  clearly I'm not doing that.  How do I create the service first, then use it in the module.config?

Comment: You may not use a service during the configuration phase. Only providers of services. After the configuration phase, services are instantiated and injected when they need to be.

Comment: @PeterKellner Why do you need to inject a service in a config phase. Probably if you state that there could be a solution. You might be trying to solve an X/Y problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multi phase in angular bootstraps process. in config phase you can just inject provider. for example you can use this code:

```
        myAppModule.config(['testServiceProvider',
            function (testServiceProvider) {
            }]);
```

To get more information please check this link:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection#configuring-providers

Comment: Thanks @Himen.  I get so frustrated with exceptions like "during the config phase, only providers can be injected (with the exception of the services in the AUTO module--$provide and $injector)"  I need to dig in more and really understand what is happening under the covers.